# Is there any way to avoid assertion error for crystal report in case of large reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

After flash EOL, we have upgraded SAP Crystal Reports, version for Eclipse software and lib, from 12 to latest CR version. Reports started working fine in HTML but there are few reports with multipage and large data where we are getting Java assertion error.

> 07:29:24,446 ERROR [][JRCCommunicationAdapter] (catalina-exec-30) detected an exception: java.lang.AssertionError.

Comment: Please explain what are the concerned versions (source and target), which "few reports" are concerned, and what exact "Java assertion error" you get.

Comment: 07:29:24,446 ERROR [][JRCCommunicationAdapter] (catalina-exec-30)  detected an exception: java.lang.AssertionError.                                                                                               we have upgraded complete Crystalreportviewer from 12 to latest CR versioon.  Most of reports are working fine but for few reports we are getting assertion error.